# Bug in Dev Console/Execute Anonymous?

Tags: apex, developer-console, debugging, execute-anonymous

I am trying to do some research, and coming across a stumbling block. `Execute Anonymous` seems to sometimes hit a statement that breaks all further debugs.

```
system.debug('Statements do appear'); // shows up
try
{
    system.debug(Timezone.getTimeZone('America/New_York')); // never shows up
    throw new DmlException();
}
catch (Exception pokemon)
{
    system.debug(pokemon); // never shows up
}
```

However, if I change the `DmlException` above to `LimitException`, it does throw, so I know the execution is not halted. What's going on?

Logging Levels:

[image: Logging Levels]

Even if I change my `LoggingLevel` on the above `debug` statements to `ERROR`, the behavior remains unchanged. But if I change the `ApexCode` level to `FINEST`, it works. Why?

Comment: In the Force.com IDE "Execute Anonymous" the debug output _does_ appear in the "Results" window.

Comment: @KeithC Interesting, I'll try it in MavensMate.

Comment: @KeithC It looks like MM always debugs `ApexCode` with `FINEST`, even if I explicitly set it to `None`.

Comment: Try using the "Open Raw Log" from the context menu in the developer console log tab. It should have a header that shows the API version and logging levels that were applied.

Comment: For what it is worth, I see both debug messages in the developer console when using a DMLException.

Comment: @DanielBallinger `37.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,NONE;CALLOUT,NONE;DB,NONE;SYSTEM,ERROR;VALIDATION,NONE;VISUALFORCE,NONE;WORKFLOW,NONE`. It doesn't seem like it changed, it just dropped the statements, even though the log isn't close to maxed out. Maybe it's a browser issue of some sort...

Comment: Does the raw log have the expected `USER_DEBUG` lines? If not, maybe there is something in converting the Timezone to a string that is breaking the logging. That said, it seems to be working for me. What if you debug a string before throwing the exception?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40025/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-daniel-ballinger).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR Looks like a bug to me. Changing the APEX_PROFILING logging level is enough to get the missing debug statements to appear.

The [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IZDTQA4) is now marked as "FIXED - WINTER '17"

---

As per the [discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40025/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-daniel-ballinger), I've reproduced this in the developer console.

If I set the log levels to only ApexCode: DEBUG and System: ERROR I get the following raw log:

```
37.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,NONE;CALLOUT,NONE;DB,NONE;SYSTEM,ERROR;VALIDATION,NONE;VISUALFORCE,NONE;WORKFLOW,NONE
Execute Anonymous: system.debug('Statements do appear'); // shows up
Execute Anonymous: try
Execute Anonymous: {
Execute Anonymous:     system.debug(Timezone.getTimeZone('America/New_York')); // never shows up
Execute Anonymous:     throw new DmlException();
Execute Anonymous: }
Execute Anonymous: catch (Exception pokemon)
Execute Anonymous: {
Execute Anonymous:     system.debug(pokemon); // never shows up
Execute Anonymous: }
09:02:05.4 (4345603)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|005O00000034lD3|twoa@fuseit.com.staging|New Zealand Standard Time|GMT+12:00
09:02:05.4 (4368694)|EXECUTION_STARTED
09:02:05.4 (4375038)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
09:02:05.4 (4944084)|USER_DEBUG|[1]|DEBUG|Statements do appear
```

Then changing the APEX_PROFILING to DEBUG and keeping the other levels the same:

[image]

```
37.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,DEBUG;CALLOUT,NONE;DB,NONE;SYSTEM,ERROR;VALIDATION,NONE;VISUALFORCE,NONE;WORKFLOW,NONE
Execute Anonymous: system.debug('Statements do appear'); // shows up
Execute Anonymous: try
Execute Anonymous: {
Execute Anonymous:     system.debug(Timezone.getTimeZone('America/New_York')); // never shows up
Execute Anonymous:     throw new DmlException();
Execute Anonymous: }
Execute Anonymous: catch (Exception pokemon)
Execute Anonymous: {
Execute Anonymous:     system.debug(pokemon); // never shows up
Execute Anonymous: }
09:05:50.3 (3550611)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|005O00000034lD3|twoa@fuseit.com.staging|New Zealand Standard Time|GMT+12:00
09:05:50.3 (3572252)|EXECUTION_STARTED
09:05:50.3 (3581418)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
09:05:50.3 (4288210)|USER_DEBUG|[1]|DEBUG|Statements do appear
09:05:50.3 (4702837)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|America/New_York
09:05:50.3 (4930773)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|System.DmlException: Script-thrown exception
09:05:50.4 (4986592)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
09:05:50.4 (4986592)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

09:05:50.4 (4986592)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

09:05:50.3 (5031944)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex
09:05:50.3 (6112119)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Raised as Support Case #13877926

I've also encountered some other [similar scenarios](https://twitter.com/FishOfPrey/status/750064887460556800) and have Support Case # 14135299 open. In one case Calling `User.Info.getTimeZone()` is causing the messages to drop. In another case they just stop appearing for several lines in a CanvasLifecycleHandler and then resume again. In both cases setting the ApexClass logging level to fine got them to appear again.

Comment: Case #13877926.

Comment: Just curious, are you able to see someone else's cases? Should I post updates if/when I receive anything significant?

Comment: No, I can't see your case details. I could potentially reference your case # if I raised my own, but I don't think that is needed here. Maybe just come back once they acknowledge it and ideally raise a known issue.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems to work as expected in my production org (`na20`). It appears to be on a higher patch than `cs19`, where I discovered the issue.

Comment: NA20 is on [Spring '16 Patch 20.7](http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/instances/NA20) versus CS19 on [Summer '16 Patch 5.4](http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/instances/CS19). So I'd guess that it was something introduced in between those two versions.

Comment: *I have replicated this issue in both summer and Spring demo Orgs and I found that the issue is happening with 'Summer Org' and working fine in 'Spring Org'. I will now escalate this case to the Tier3 and will share an update on Monday.* We'll see what they say...

Comment: I know have 7 identical comments starting 5/23 that go: *This is a follow up on your case #13877926. As I am still waiting for a response from Tier3 and as soon as I get any feedback from their end, I will get back to you...* Fun.

Comment: @AdrianLarson They could at least put in some effort and rephrase it every now and then.

Comment: Honestly, I prefer it this way. I've had some of them insist on calling me with basically the same message. Apathy is by far a preferable attitude if all you can say is: "We're still looking into it."

Comment: New update. *...we strongly suspect that this is a bug and therefore we raised an investigation mentioning the results with different Orgs. Since, it is currently with R&D team, we are waiting for the response from thier (sic) end.* Not resolved, but it sounds like it will finally be reported as a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about this. I've started a similar Case (14135299) where debug messages were disappearing mid log in a CanvasLifecycleHandler (unrelated to getTimeZone()). I've added a reference back to your case to the support notes.

Comment: R&D has created a bug for this issue. It is now a [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IZDTQA4)